# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, when trying to import an ejs file inside of a lambda function, in serverless project

Tags: webpack, ejs, serverless

In one of my lambda functions, I am trying to send an email using SES, for the body of the email I am using ejs, so that I can pass some data and send a customized email to the recipient. It was successfully, when Serverless was not configured with webpack. After adding webpack, it is returning Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory. Please anyone help me figure out how to resolve this.

I tried adding a new rule for ejs files in the webpack.config.js file.

```
const slsw = require('serverless-webpack');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

module.exports = {
  entry: slsw.lib.entries,
  target: 'node',
  // Generate sourcemaps for proper error messages
  devtool: 'source-map',
  // Since 'aws-sdk' is not compatible with webpack,
  // we exclude all node dependencies
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  mode: slsw.lib.webpack.isLocal ? 'development' : 'production',
  optimization: {
    // We no not want to minimize our code.
    minimize: true,
  },
  performance: {
    // Turn off size warnings for entry points
    hints: false,
  },
  // Run babel on all .js files and skip those in node_modules
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: __dirname,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.ejs$/,
        loader: 'ejs-loader',
        query: {
            variable: 'data',
            interpolate : '\\{\\{(.+?)\\}\\}',
            evaluate : '\\[\\[(.+?)\\]\\]'
        }
      }
    ],
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

try add this plugin

```
plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: "index.html",
        template: "./src/index.tpl.ejs",
        withAnalytics: false,
        hash: true,
        showErrors: true,
        chunksSortMode: "dependency"
    })]
```